# SimpleCursorAdapter and ListView problem

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a problem displaying an records from my db in listview. This is my code

```
public class FirstTab extends ListActivity {    


private DatabaseHelper dbhelper;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.first);

    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);


    String[] columns = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.colTitle , DatabaseHelper.colDate};

    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, columns, to);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
}
```

and

```
...
public Cursor getAllNotes()
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

     return db.query(noteTable, new String [] {colTitle, colDesc, colDate}, null, null, null, null, null);

 }
...
```

if you need more , here is repo https://github.com/grzegorz-l/myHomeworks

When i start my app it crash at the beggining (RuntimeException). If I comment 2 last lines in onCreate method it run but ofc doesn't show anything.

Thanks in advance

Greg

Comment: post the details of the exception message/stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass `getApplicationContext()` when creating SimpleCursorAdapter. Use `this` instead, i.e., the context of your ListActivity.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, columns, to);
```

Comment: i copied bad code ;p in repo is correctly "this" but it doesn't help if there is this instead of getApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

Your FirstTab.java file is extending a ListActivity. This means that it's layout file has to contain a ListView with android:id set to:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Also, your FirstTab.java has it's layout pointing to note_entry.xml. It should either point to a layout which has a ListView of above description in it or not be extended by a ListActivity.